# UWP: read input bytes from HID Capture Card

Tags: c#, audio, uwp, capture, hid

My UWP application identifies Capture Card as HidDevice:

```
HidDevice device = await HidDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceId, Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
```

Is it possible read input bytes from HID Capture Card? (Like [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) does).
Maybe some DataReader on InputStream?

My hid capability in manifest:

```
<DeviceCapability Name="humaninterfacedevice">

          <Device Id="vidpid:534d 2109">
              <Function Type="usage:0005 *" />
              <Function Type="usage:FF00 0001" />
              <Function Type="usage:ff00 *" />
          </Device>
          
      </DeviceCapability>
```

Answer (score 1):

> read input bytes from HID Capture Card

Sure, you could read `HidDevice` input bytes. HidDevice contains `InputReportReceived` event that could use to display data when data input. For more please refer official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.humaninterfacedevice.hiddevice?view=winrt-19041#examples).

```
device.InputReportReceived += async (sender, args) =>
{
    HidInputReport inputReport = args.Report;
    IBuffer buffer = inputReport.Data;

    // Create a DispatchedHandler as we are interracting with the UI directly and the
    // thread that this function is running on might not be the UI thread; 
    // if a non-UI thread modifies the UI, an exception is thrown.

    await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(
        CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
        new DispatchedHandler(() =>
        {
            info.Text += "\nHID Input Report: " + inputReport.ToString() +
            "\nTotal number of bytes received: " + buffer.Length.ToString();
        }));
};
```

Comment: I already tried this code with youtube video on background, but InputReportReceived event never fired. In OBS studio it works.

Comment: Could you explain *in obs studio it works*? And have you tried above code in the foreground ?

Comment: It means OBS studio records audio successfully for youtube video is opened in a browser. I ran UWP app with your code from foreground process.

Comment: Could you share more detail about your hid device info?

Comment: Please check this document, please check if you have add humanInterfaceDevice [capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.humaninterfacedevice?view=winrt-19041)

Comment: It was already added to manifest. I updated my question, you can hid capability that I use. I think without this, I'll get NULL from function HidDevice.FromIdAsync, so it isn't my case.

Comment: @Rougher. the issue looks you used wrong vid/pid, Please refer this [blog](http://www.idevstream.com/?p=322) and check if your pid and vid are correct.